# LoopbackJS 3.x, how to enable delete all matching instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, loopbackjs

By [default](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/PersistedModel-REST-API#delete-all-matching-instances) in Loopback delete all matching instances is not exposed over REST API.
How to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any reference to the documentation, but I successfully tested this.

TLDR:
Put in this in your `model.js` or in `server.js`

```
app.models.<model>.remoteMethod('destroyAll', {
          description: 'Delete all matching records.',
          accessType: 'WRITE',
          accepts: [
            {arg: 'where', type: 'object', description: 'filter.where object'},
            {arg: 'options', type: 'object', http: 'optionsFromRequest'},
          ],
          returns: {
            arg: 'count',
            type: 'object',
            description: 'The number of instances deleted',
            root: true,
          },
          http: {verb: 'del', path: '/'},
          // shared: false,
        });
```

The above is simply the remote method declaration from the [source](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/72d48c3bfa478ec0d05b2b168bbab321f4423918/lib/persisted-model.js#L821), except the `shared: false` is commented out.

Comment: I would not like to rewrite the method, but only set "shared" to true

Comment: Technically you're only rewriting how the method is being presented to the api, but yes, there is probably a much more elegant solution.

Comment: I found a cleaner solution. Modifying config.json's remoting object: "remoting": {
  "context": false,
  ...
  "sharedMethods": {
    "*": true,
    ...
  }
}

Comment: You can answer your own question, though that will expose all `destroyAll` methods to REST which may not be ideal