# Delete all the row that matches a filter

Tags: loopbackjs

How can I delete all the row that matchs a specific filter ?

Something like

```
DELETE /items?filter={"where":{"color":"blue"}}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could refer to the loopback documentation to [delete persisted model](http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#persistedmodel-destroyall) and [filter](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html)

In your NODE code

```
Books.destroyAll({"or":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}, callback)
```

In your REST API

```
http://localhost:3000/api/Books?filter={"where":{"or":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}}
```

If you update your question with the code that is not working for you, I could update the answer to address your problem.

Comment: I get a 404 with this error : Shared class  \"translations\" has no method handling DELETE /?filter={"where":{"or":[{"id":1}]}}

Comment: It is quite difficult to find out what is going wrong without seeing your code. Could you probably add a code snippet to show where it is going wrong?

Comment: Well I don't have any code, I just defined a common model and I want to use the generated default methods.

Comment: In that case, the filter you specified in your question should work just fine. Please try it out and update a screenshot of the error if you get one :)

Comment: Simply does not work, it is necessary to consider the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858943/loopbackjs-3-x-how-to-enable-delete-all-matching-instances

Comment: Also in the REST API request must be of the form:
`DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/Books?where={"or":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}`

Comment: Hello @Sashi, I'm sorry but your answer is incorrect, I tried to follow it and it does not work.
It is for those who will read you the answer, I have the correct version in the comments.
Details: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-updating-and-deleting-data.html#deleting-data

Comment: @MaxAlex The right thing for you to do in that case is to write it as an answer to this question instead of tearing me up and downvoting my answer. There are many answers on stackoverflow which work at the time it is written but dont work later. The right approach is to add whatever worked for you in a new answer for the benefit of people who read it years later. I cant go back and edit all my answers as soon as something changes. FYI I dont even use loopback anymore.